# SceneKit animation with line drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, line, scenekit

I would like to get some help with a scenekit related problem.
I have a dae (collada) file. The scene contains a mesh with bones and one animation. The bones will be moving in the animation and i would like to draw a line from a fix point to a selected moving bone. The expected result should looks like this: [img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W0fI.png), [img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUuAU.png). One end of the line is fixed and the other end of the line should follow the animated bone. Like a rubber band. I tried to implement it in a sample project but i was not able to get the line follow the animation. I don't know how to follow the animation's position per frame and i don't know how could i update the line on the screen. The code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import SceneKit;
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>

@interface ViewController ()<SCNSceneRendererDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet SCNView *scnView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SCNNode *topBone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SCNNode *lineNode;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scnView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
    self.scnView.playing = YES;
    self.scnView.delegate = self;   // Set the delegate to myself. Because during the animation i would like to redraw the line to the correct position
    // I have an animation with bones.
    SCNScene *mainScene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/test.dae"];      // Loading the test scene
    self.topBone = [mainScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"TopBone" recursively:YES];   // Find the top bone. I would like to draw a line between the top of the bone and a fix point (5,5,0)
    self.lineNode = [self lineFrom:self.topBone.presentationNode.position to:SCNVector3Make(5.0, 5.0, 0.0)];   // Create a node for the line and draw the line
    self.scnView.scene = mainScene;     // Set the scene
    [mainScene.rootNode addChildNode:self.lineNode];    // Add the line node to the scene
}

// I would like to use the render delegate to update the line position. Maybe this is not the right solution...
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer willRenderScene:(SCNScene *)scene atTime:(NSTimeInterval)time {
    SCNVector3 v = self.topBone.presentationNode.position;  // Problem1: The position of the top bone never change. It is always the same value. It is not follow the animation
    // Problem 2: if I could get the correct bone position in the animation frame, how could I redraw the line in the Node in every frame?
    glLineWidth(20);        // Set the line width
}

- (SCNNode *)lineFrom:(SCNVector3)p1 to:(SCNVector3)p2 {        // Draw a line between two points and return it as a node
    int indices[] = {0, 1};
    SCNVector3 positions[] = { p1, p2 };
    SCNGeometrySource *vertexSource = [SCNGeometrySource geometrySourceWithVertices:positions count:2];
    NSData *indexData = [NSData dataWithBytes:indices length:sizeof(indices)];
    SCNGeometryElement *element = [SCNGeometryElement geometryElementWithData:indexData primitiveType:SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypeLine primitiveCount:1 bytesPerIndex:sizeof(int)];
    SCNGeometry *line = [SCNGeometry geometryWithSources:@[vertexSource] elements:@[element]];
    line.materials.firstObject.diffuse.contents = [UIColor redColor];
    SCNNode *lineNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:line];
    return lineNode;
}

@end
```